# Symfony2 login form redirects to home page instead of redirecting to referer URL

Tags: symfony, authentication

I got a Symfony2 project set up with a form-based login.

This is what my `security.yml` configuration looks like:

```
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  /login
            check_path:  /login_check
            default_target_path: /home
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }             
    - { path: ^/login, access: "isAnonymous()" }
    - { path: ^/login_check, access: "isAnonymous()" }
    - { path: ^/register, access: "isAnonymous()" }
```

Generally, logging in and out works just fine, but when logging in, I'm getting redirected to `/` instead of the requested URL (referer). This happens regardless of whether the `use_referer` is set to `true` or `false`.

When setting `always_use_default_target_path` to `true`, I get redirected to the default path (`/home`) instead of `/`, which does make sense.

Can anybody give me a hint on why I'm being redirected to `/` instead of the referer URL?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you don't want to customize anything why don't you try for default settings like `form_login: ~`, `logout: ~`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was my bad... I somehow forgot that some time ago I added the following line to my login action's form template (`login.html.twig`):

`<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/" />`

After commenting it, suddenly everything is working again... ;-)